# Updating a pyplot 3d scatter plot in a loop, grid lines overlap points

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, scatter

I am updating a 3d scatter plot with every iteration of a loop. When the plot is redrawn, the gridlines "go through" or "cover" the points, which makes my data more difficult to visualize. If I build a single 3d plot (no loop updating) this does not happen. The code below demonstrates the simplest case:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import time

X = np.random.rand(100, 3)*10
Y = np.random.rand(100, 3)*5

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2])
plt.draw()

for i in range(0, 20):
    time.sleep(3)   #make changes more apparent/easy to see

    Y = np.random.rand(100, 3)*5
    ax.cla()    
    ax.scatter(Y[:, 0], Y[:, 1], Y[:, 2])
    plt.draw()
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: I didn't get what was the pb, could you clarify ? What do you want to do ?

Comment: If you update a matplotlib3d axes in a loop, e.g. when using the Funcanimation, the grid which is normally in the background, overlays the plotted surface. I updated the question.

Comment: but the edit needs to be peer reviewed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like [MaxNoe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25192499/3406193) is right in the sense that the problem is in the `ax.cla()`or `plt.cla()` call. In fact it seems it is something like a [known issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/750).

Then there is a problem, since the clear axes method doesn't work in 3D plots and for 3D scatters there is no clean way to change the coordinates of the data points (a la `sc.set_data(new_values)`), as discussed [in this mail list](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/3d-animated-scatter-plot-td39721.html) (I didn't find anything more recent).

In the mail list, however, Ben Roon points to a workaround that might be useful for you, too.

#### Workaround:

You need to set the new coordinates of the datapoints in the internal `_ofsets3d` variable of the `Line3DCollection`object returned by the `scatter` function.

Your example adapted would look like:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import time

X = np.random.rand(100, 3)*10
Y = np.random.rand(100, 3)*5

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
sc = ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2])
fig.show()

for i in range(0, 20):
    plt.pause(1)

    Y = np.random.rand(100, 3)*5

    sc._offsets3d = (Y[:,0], Y[:,1], Y[:,2])
    plt.draw()
```

Comment: If anybody wonders, it is also possible to change the number of elements to plot in every iteration of the loop:      
`Y = np.random.rand(np.random.randint(200), 3)*5` works fine

Answer (score 3):

I could narrow it down to the use of cla():

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2,2), np.linspace(-2,2))

ax.plot_surface(x,y, x**2+y**2)
fig.savefig("fig_a.png")

ax.cla()
ax.plot_surface(x,y, x**2+y**2)

fig.savefig("fig_b.png")
```

these are the resulting plots:
[image: fig_a]
[image: fig_b]

Answer (score 1):

This is but a workaround, as it does not resolve the issue with `ax.cla()` pointed out by [MaxNoe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25192499/3406193). It is also not particularly pretty since it clears the entire figure, however it does the desired task:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2,2), np.linspace(-2,2))

ax1.plot_surface(x,y, x**2+y**2)
fig1.savefig("fig_a.png")

fig1.clf()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax1.plot_surface(x,y, x**2+y**2)

fig1.savefig("fig_b.png")
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that you need to render the whole figure again, generate the axes and then plot the data. It takes about three times longer to update the figure than modifying directly the data of the current scatter plot... (almost 0.1s in my PC, which is already clearly noticeable)

Comment: @mgab I totally agree with you. It is not a nice solution. But as it seems with `ax.cla()` it shows - for now at least - not the desired behaviour. Using `fig.clf()` takes long but at least shows the desired behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest using `ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')` instead of `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')` .

Comment: what exactly is the differecnce between those two?

Comment: same result, grid is over the plotted objects.